# GitHub: how to remove another person's fork of a private repo?

Tags: github, private, git-fork

At work some developers created forks of our private repos.  They have since left and now there are ~40 forks of company code in various personal accounts.

If we need to restrict that code, does GitHub provide a mechanism for removing their forks of our projects?  Or is that something that our past employees need to do themselves?

Answer (score 3):

If they have forked the private repos into their own accounts based on the fact that they had access to your org, removing them from the org will yank the forks from their accounts (i.e. you only have to remove them from the org)

If this is not the case, you can use the process outline here: https://help.github.com/articles/dmca-takedown-policy/ to ask github to take down the repos (assumes you do own the copyright on the code - which you should if it's in private repos).